# Adobe AIR stream publish breaks on iOS devices

Tags: apache-flex, air, netstream, netconnection

I am using Adobe Air 13.0 to upload a streaming video to Flash Media Server.
This works fine on all Android devices, but on iOS devices (both iPad and iPhone) the publish stream breaks after several time (could be 10 seconds, could be 5 minutes).

Here are my relevant code segments:

```
private function CreateConnection():void
{
  netconn = new NetConnection();
  netconn.client = this;
  netconn.objectEncoding = flash.net.ObjectEncoding.AMF3;
  netconn.connect(rtmpPath);
  netconn.addEventListener("netStatus", netConnection_eventHandler);
}
```

...

```
netStream = new NetStream(netconn, NetStream.CONNECT_TO_FMS);  
netStream.client=this;
netStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,netConnection_eventHandler);
netStream.attachCamera(cam);
netStream.attachAudio(mic);
netStream.publish(XXXX, "record");
```

Thanks,
Koby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved. Found the solution by changing FMS settings.

Comment: What was the solution? What did you change?